# Dynamically updating the template's Html in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a custom directive called customStyles, which is defined as :

```
scrollbackApp.directive('customStyles', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<style> {{styleString}} </style>',
        scope: {
            conversations : '='
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
            $scope.$watch('conversations', function(value){
                // calculate str based on value
                $scope.styleString = str;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm adding this directive to the body of my Html view:

```
<body>
  <custom-styles conversations="convList"> </custom-styles>
</body>
```

And the value of `convList` changes inside the parent controller scope. As present, when the above directive renders to Html, the `{{styleString}}` binding remains as a string, instead of changing into it's value. I want the html of the directive to change dynamically based on the value of `styleString`. Is this possible in Angular?

Comment: Can you do an example of styleString ? btw function(value) should be function(str)

Answer (score 1):

You should rename directive tag in view:

```
<custom-styles conversations="convList"> </custom-styles>
```

Here is working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aOxf3fgS7Tc0sOyCXoBV?p=preview

Comment: I changed `str` to `value` because I did not know your str calculation logic. And also I changed tag `<style>` to `<span>` to see the model changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had originally used `custom-styles` as the directive name. It was a typo in my question. Even so, I should check to see what you are doing different here.

Comment: Nothing different. Only changed the directive name!